# Mapping from string "aa=bb" to Dictionary<string, string>

Tags: c#

I am converting a input like :

```
aa=bb
Fruit1=Potato
Fruite2=Banana
```

Into a Dictionary, using this code.

```
string tmp = "\r\naa=bb\r\nFruit1=Potato\r\nFruite2=Banana";
Dictionary<string, string> tempValueList = new Dictionary<string, string>();

var lines = tmp.Split(new[] { "\r\n", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
foreach (var line in lines)
{
    var keyValue = line.Split(new[] { '=' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    tempValueList.Add(keyValue[0],keyValue[1]);
}

tempIniObject.Key = key;
tempIniObject.ValueList = tempValueList;
```

This is simple, but I believe there is a mutch classier way to do it.

Comment: I wanted to post this question on So but as this is not broken code, and I'am looking for a way to improve it, I think it's a better fit here. If the question is not worthy or the code to short, Fell free to comment or dw.

Comment: Based on the `tempIniObject` name, I assume you're trying to parse a `.ini` file in general? If so, can you include the remainder of the code to do so? We may be able to help you *more* if we see the whole process.

Comment: @Ebrown, I am currently looking into Ini Reader to see if there is was to use the string as a declaration. I'am reading a blob in a csv.

Comment: Faceing the [Table 12 specification](http://thedailywtf.com/articles/table-12), my brain try to have fun on a part of the code. It will be hard to Edit it into a working code with more context as this Csv column threatment will give me TemplateKey and Value for different Template later in the csv.

Comment: That's fine - you don't *have* to add more. Your question is mostly fine as it stands (it would be nice to have a little more 'plain text' in it, as to what you want to achieve) but it's a pretty self-explanatory problem. I'll see if I can't give you some pointers later today.

Comment: No definition for key.  No check for split length.  No check for duplicate key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not to use regular expression? Your task can be solved with this code:

```
var dictionary = Regex.Matches(tmp, "(?<key>.+)=(?<value>.+)")
                      .OfType<Match>()
                      .Where(m => m.Success)
                      .ToDictionary(m => m.Groups["key"].Value.Trim(),
                                    m => m.Groups["value"].Value.Trim());
```

Comment: This will onyl work if the string is already splitted on new lines and `m.Groups["key"]` this is not enougth. You need to use the `.Value` property of the group.

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing out to missed `.Value`. Fixed it. As for assumption about new lines in input string it is the form of input according to OP. Or am I missing something? :) I've tested on `"\r\naa=bb\r\nFruit1=Potato\r\nFruite2=Banana"` and it works correctly.

Comment: Oh, the `.` does not mach a new line... and again learned something new :-)

Comment: @t3chb0t most regex engines allow passing an option that does change that. For C# regex that's `RegexOptions.Singleline` if I read the docs correctly

Answer (score 3):

Here are a few comments

1. Write unit tests for this kind of thing.

   I'm assuming you have something like:

   ```
   public static class IniFile
   {
       public static IReadOnlyDictionary<string, string> Parse(string contents)
       {
           ...
       }
   }
   ```
2. If so returning a type `IniFile` that wraps the dictionary is probably a good idea.
3. Before `tempValueList.Add(keyValue[0], keyValue[1]);` you can check that the length is 2 and throw a `FormatException` with a descriptive message if it is not. Perhaps what line was malformed and what the expected syntax is. As it is now it will throw an `IndexOutOfRangeException` which is less helpful.
4. I prefer `var` for things like `var tempValueList = new Dictionary<string, string>();` shorter and removes redundancy but it is a style choice.
5. `Regex` is a nice fit for what you are doing but string split is fine.
6. What you have can be written using LINQ but I prefer how it is written.

What you have is fine assuming you have at least one test for a happy path.